# Moving Strings between UserControls not Working

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to pass strings between forms. Why does it not? Am I missing something or is it an error in the program or what?

On UserControl3

```
 UserControl1 u1;

    public UserControl3()
    {
           u1 = new UserControl1();
           InitializeComponent();
    }
```

On UserControl3

```
public void materialCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (materialCheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                u1.toUserControl3 = "GOINTHEBOX!";
            }
            else
            {
                u1.toUserControl3 = string.Empty;
            }


        }
```

On UserControl1

```
public string toUserControl3
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox1.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

On UserControl1

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `Text` property on a control through a piece of code doesn't necessarily mean the value control will update. Typically you need some sort of binding between your property, in this case `toUserControl3`, and your control. You need a way to tell your control that value changed so it knows to update.

You could accomplish databinding in the following way:

**Create a new class to handle state and binding**: This eliminated any need to pass controls into constructors of other controls.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TextBoxText => CheckBoxChecked ? "GOINTOTHEBOX!" : string.Empty;

    public bool CheckBoxChecked
    {
        get { return _checkBoxChecked; }
        set 
        { 
            _checkBoxChecked = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxChecked"); 
        }
    }

    private bool _checkBoxChecked;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**This is your main form**

```
public void Form1
{
    public Form1(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        UserControl1.DataBindings.Add("TextBoxTextProperty", viewModel, "TextBoxText");
        UserControl3.DataBindings.Add("MaterialCheckBoxCheckedProperty", viewModel, "CheckBoxChecked");
    }
}
```

**UserControl1**

```
public void UserControl1()
{
    public string TextBoxTextProperty
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

**UserControl3**

```
public void UserControl3()
{
    public bool MaterialCheckBoxCheckedProperty
    {
        get { return materialCheckBox1.Checked; }
        set { materialCheckBox1.Checked = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just realized there may be a better way, because you are dealing with user controls not forms and you don't want a dependency on your view model injected into your user control